# LINQ query joining two tables together to return values that are false

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that joins two tables together by matching method names. Within the table I need to look for a 'global' value and if found compare the children elements in methods called 'parameters' against each other assuring that both the tables has an equal counterpart and if one methods parameters does not match any of the others then returns false.

Below is an example of the results. We can see that seqEquals has found a 'method' that does not equal any of the others, however, the LINQ query returns all values and I'd like to only extract on false of 'seqEquals' I have tried putting the string compare within the 'where' clause however the results did not compare all against each other as expected.

```
{ mOneName = GetItemsJSON, seqEqual = False, mOneParm = [
  {
    "name": "itemTypes",
    "type": "List"
  },
  {
    "name": "textSearch",
    "type": "String"
  }
], mTwoParm = [
  {
    "name": "propertyId",
    "type": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "revClassIds",
    "type": "List"
  },
  {
    "name": "itemTypes",
    "type": "List"
  },
  {
    "name": "textSearch",
    "type": "String"
  },
  {
    "name": "eventId",
    "type": "String"
  }
] }
```

The C# code

```
        var ST1 = firstOrgST["records"][0]["SymbolTable"]["methods"];
        var ST2 = secondOrgST["records"][0]["SymbolTable"]["methods"];

        // joins both tables and pulls the methods containing global from the joins
        var STDiff =
            from one in ST1
            join two in ST2
                on one.Value<String>("name") equals two.Value<string>("name")
            where one["modifiers"].Values().Contains("global")
            select new
            {
                mOneName = one["name"],
                seqEqual = one["parameters"].ToString() == two["parameters"].ToString(),
                mOneParm = one["parameters"],
                mTwoParm = two["parameters"]
            };

        var errorFound = false;
        var errorMethod = "";

        foreach (var i in STDiff)
        {    Console.WriteLine(i);
            if (!i.seqEqual)
            {
                errorFound = true;
                errorMethod = i.mOneName.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        // if error is found prints to console the class name as well as the method name
        if (errorFound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(symbolTable) + " on method: " + errorMethod + " has different parameters.\n");
            isDifferent = true;
        }
```

Example of data: This is table one. Table two may have different params

```
{
  "SymbolTable": {
    "methods": [
      {
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "TestVisible"
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "column": 20,
          "line": 1056
        },
        "modifiers": [
          "private"
        ],
        "name": "GetItemsJSON",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "propertyId",
            "type": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "revClassIds",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "itemTypes",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "itemCategories",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "textSearch",
            "type": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "eventId",
            "type": "String"
          }
        ],
        "references": [],
        "returnType": "String",
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "annotations": [],
        "location": {
          "column": 26,
          "line": 4313
        },
        "modifiers": [
          "static",
          "global"
        ],
        "name": "GetItemsJSON",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "itemTypes",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "textSearch",
            "type": "String"
          }
        ],
        "references": [],
        "returnType": "String",
        "type": null
      },
      {
        "annotations": [],
        "location": {
          "column": 26,
          "line": 4316
        },
        "modifiers": [
          "static",
          "global"
        ],
        "name": "GetItemsJSON",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "propertyId",
            "type": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "revClassIds",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "itemTypes",
            "type": "List"
          },
          {
            "name": "textSearch",
            "type": "String"
          },
          {
            "name": "eventId",
            "type": "String"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to show what your table data looks like and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: The output is the json I have posted.  All I really need is the method name returned.  The tables are over 25k lines of code I can do my best to shorten it as much as possible.

Comment: Would `where one["modifiers"].Values().Contains("global") && one["parameters"].ToString() != two["parameters"].ToString()` work ?

Comment: No.  It does not compare all the parameters as there are multiple of each.

Comment: In order to understand why the parameters check doesn't work, it's important to understand what data type it is. Can you post some sample data - 4,5 rows will do.

Comment: @HiralDesai added

Comment: Are you able to cast the parameters into a List<Param> where Param is a class containing name and type as property?

Comment: External of the linq query?

Comment: No within the Linq query itself if possible. I haven't done it before but just checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194073/discussion-between-hiral-desai-and-nicole-phillips).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you convert your datatable into a list of objects and then run your linq query.

1) Use a generic method like this for conversion of DataTable to list of objects

```
private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)  
{  
    List<T> data = new List<T>();  
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)  
    {  
        T item = GetItem<T>(row);  
        data.Add(item);  
    }  
    return data;  
}

private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)  
{  
    Type temp = typeof(T);  
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();  

    foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)  
    {  
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())  
        {  
            if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)  
                pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);  
            else  
                continue;  
        }  
    }  
    return obj;  
}
```

2) Use Linq query like this on the list of objects

```
    var ST1 = myTableData.ToList();
    var ST2 = myTableData.ToList();

    var STDiff = from one in ST1 
                 join two in ST2 
                 on one.name equals two.name
                 where one.modifiers.Contains("global")
            select new
            {
                mOneName = one.name,
                seqEqual = CompareParamsAndGetMatchingIndex(one.parameters, two.parameters),
                mOneParm = one.parameters,
                mTwoParm = two.parameters
            };

private int CompareParamsAndGetMatchingIndex(Parameter[] items1, Parameter[] items2) 
{
    if (items1.Length > items2.Length)
    {
        return items2.Select((Parameter p, int i) => p.Equals(items1[i]) ? 1 : 0).Sum();
    }
    else 
    {
        return items1.Select((Parameter p, int i) => p.Equals(items2[i]) ? 1 : 0).Sum();
    }   
}

public class SymbolTableRoot
{
    public Symboltable SymbolTable { get; set; }
}

public class Symboltable
{
    public Method[] methods { get; set; }
}

public class Method
{
    public Annotation[] annotations { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string[] modifiers { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Parameter[] parameters { get; set; }
    public object[] references { get; set; }
    public string returnType { get; set; }
    public object type { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public int line { get; set; }
}

public class Annotation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter : IEquatable<Parameter>
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Parameter other)
    {
        return other?.name == name && other?.type == type;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not compare all the parameters as there are multiple of each.  It returns on first false.  It is much like comparing param[0] to param[0,0,0,0, 1].  Need it to say okay i found not matching at 1 and then return the name.  Both 'arrays' will have multiple values.

Comment: I have amended the answer to do that. It's a little complex but for what you're trying to do, you have to convert the values into typed object because of the way they're stored.